# VMWare Workstation and network isolation

Tags: networking, security, vlan, vmware-workstation, dmz

When I install VNC or some other RAT to a container in my VMWare Workstation machine box, what ways can I prevent access to my local network and other machines on my network.

Is this where setting up a DMZ would come in handy? Or setup VLans? I currently have a NETGEAR FS 726T Switch which supports VLans.

EDIT: I would like to allow someone from the outside to access this particular container.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest answer here would be to use the NAT virtual network of VMWare Workstation. The NAT vnic/vnet uses your pc to NAT to the rest of the world. By default nothing initiated from the outside should be able to come in, but the VM's would still be able to get out to the internet and other machines on the LAN.

If the VM's don't need internet access, then you can just add them to a private virtual netowrk or remove the virtual network card altogether.

Comment: I forgot to add, if the VM's don't need internet access, then you can just add them to a private virtual netowrk or remove the virtual network card altogether.